# Running driver for Java Swing MVC does not show View

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

I'm not very knowledgeable in MVC so forgive me if this is a basic question.

I'm currently working on a school project, and I can't seem to get the program to run properly. I've tried compiling these java files with no errors coming out. However, when I try to run the MenuDriver.java file, the GUI window/View does not pop-up, and the program just ends.

MenuController.java

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class MenuController implements ActionListener {
    private StartMenu start;

    public MenuController(StartMenu start) {
        this.start = start;
        start.setListeners (this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Play")) {
            start.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

MenuDriver.java

```
public class MenuDriver
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        StartMenu start = new StartMenu();
        MenuController controller = new MenuController (start);
    }
}
```

StartMenu.java

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class StartMenu extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton btnPlay = new JButton("");
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StartMenu frame = new StartMenu();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public StartMenu() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 650, 450);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/smthn1.png")).getImage();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        label.setBounds(84, 58, 457, 183);
        contentPane.add(label);

        Image img2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/smthn2.png")).getImage();
        btnPlay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        btnPlay.setBounds(222, 251, 166, 64);
        contentPane.add(btnPlay);

        btnPlay.setActionCommand("Play");
    }

    public void setListeners (ActionListener a) {
        btnPlay.addActionListener (a);
    }
}
```

I'm losing my mind, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I try to run the MenuDriver.java file, the GUI window/View does not pop-up, and the program just ends.

You never make the frame visible, so the program just ends.

You need to make the frame visible at the end of your constructor:

```
btnPlay.setActionCommand("Play");
setVisible( true );
```

Also, learn to use [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to position components. Using a null layout with setBounds(...) is not the way Swing was designed to be used.